# Null Reference Exception at List.Where().ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to use the below line of code to extract necessary data from a list and ingest into a different list. Most of the time I am able to get this process success. But at some point, I am getting a null reference exception. I did check for null in the first place for the source list.

```
 List<Employees> marketingEmployeeList = new List<Employees>();
                if (totalEmployeeList != null && totalEmployeeList.Any())
                {
                    marketingEmployeeList = totalEmployeeList.Where(x => x.department ==                     "Marketing").ToList();
                }
                If(marketingEmployeeList.Any())
                {
                    CallMethod(marketingEmployeeList);
                }
```

My stack trace contains the below

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.ToList() at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Previously I didnot check null for totalEmployeeList. I got the null error But later even after i checked null I get the null reference error

Comment: It potentially means that one of the items in the list is null.

Comment: What does `totalEmployeeList` contain? Is there any chance it contains nulls?

Comment: You gain nothing by using `Any()`. This will iterate the source unless it's a List<> or array, in which case it will just check the length. Just call `.Where(..)`. If you want to exclude nulls, use `Where(x => x?.department == "whatever")`. The expression `x?.department` returns `null` if `x` is null and fails the comparison

Comment: You can simplify all the code and avoid an extra allocation with `var marketingEmployeeList = totalEmployeeList?.Where(x => x?.department == "something").ToList(); if (marketingEmployeeList is !=null ) { CallMethod(...); }`. The null-safe operators `?.` return null if the argument on the left is null instead of throwing. The compiler is smart enough at least in C# 11 to understand that the `marketing..` variable isn't null inside the branch and won't complain if `CallMethod` requires a non-nullable argument